# What is the scope of a variable declared with 'var' inside of a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, scope, var

I saw another post with the same question and it seemed to have differing explanations. Online resources also seem to have conflicting explanations, unless I am misunderstanding something.

MDN says:

"The scope of a variable declared with var is one of the following curly-brace-enclosed syntaxes that most closely contains the var statement:

Function body

Static initialization block

Or if none of the above applies:

The current module, for code running in module mode

The global scope, for code running in script mode."

My interpretation of this is that the answer to my question would be local scope - local to the function.

w3schools on the other hand says:

"Variables declared with the var keyword can NOT have block scope.

Variables declared inside a { } block can be accessed from outside the block."

If my understanding that function scope is an example of block scope, then this tells me that variables declared inside of a function (which is a block) cannot have block scope - and thus has global scope.

freeCodeCamp says:

"Variables which are declared without the let or const keywords are automatically created in the global scope"

Which also suggests to me that variables declared inside of a function with the var keyword have global scope.

So I am confused as to what the answer is, does a variable declared with the var keyword inside of a function (in the context of JavaScript) have global scope or local scope (local to the function)?

I am sure there is something I am misunderstanding - perhaps a misuse of terminology. Thank you in advance.

Comment: "most closely contains the `var` variable" and the first thing listed, "Function body", explicitly answer your question.

Comment: The quote from free code camp is wrong with respect to `var`.

Comment: "block scope" and "function scope" mean different things. Functions are associated with a block of code, but that's not what "block scope" means. It means a block inside `{ }` after something like an `if` or `while` etc.

Comment: You should have done a trivial experiment `function fn() { var x = 42; } fn(); console.log(typeof x);` and you'd have verified whether the variable is global or not.

Comment: Super simple: If the `var` is anywhere within a function, it's scoped to that function. If not, it's Global.

Comment: @Pointy 
""most closely contains the var variable" and the first thing listed, "Function body", explicitly answer your question. "

  Right, but other sources present information that seem to explicitly answer my 
  question as well, like for ex freeCodeCamp, which you pointed out is incorrect.     
  So I asked hoping to get clarity on which info is correct.

Comment: @Pointy ""block scope" and "function scope" mean different things. Functions are associated with a block of code, but that's not what "block scope" means. 
It means a block inside { } after something like an if or while etc"

So then with regards to scope, is a block considered to be anything inside { } with the exception of functions, and only functions? Or are there other exceptions I should know about? As you can probably tell I am fairly new to JS and in my mind if a block is a segment of code wrapped in { } then a function would count as a block.

Comment: @VLAZ I could have, but opted to ask as opposed to make an observation that may have been incorrect. For ex I could do console.log("9" - 1); and come to the conclusion that you can do arithmetic between a string and a number. But of course that is not the case when using the + operator. In addition, various sources were presenting conflicting information so I was hoping to be pointed to which source was correct.

Comment: @journeywithjavascript At the function level, in other words, when the closest `{ }` is the block boundary of a function, `var` and `let` are (almost) the same. All the inner blocks (except nested functions) however are where `var` and `let` differ. In an `if` block, a `let` variable is completely local to that block; a `var` in that same block, however, is scoped to the function.

Comment: @Pointy I see, thanks